# NW.js fullscreen mode is actually borderless windowed, not true fullscreen

Tags: javascript, chromium, nw.js

I'm working on a game using NW.js, one that I'd like to be fullscreen. The fullscreen mode does in fact make the game fullscreen, but it's not true fullscreen like many other games, it's borderless windowed.

This is affecting performance for other players, so I'm trying my best to get true fullscreen. Is this not possible with NW.js, or even anything Chromium?

My NW.js manifest:

```
"window": {
  "title": "Slapshot",
  "frame": false,
  "width": 800,
  "height": 600,
  "icon": "assets/textures/icon.png",
  "fullscreen": true,
  "toolbar": false
},
```

Comment: NW.js/Chromium is a browser, not a game engine; it was probably never meant to support real fullscreen for games. If your game is using a canvas and WebGL you should find a real node.js game engine.

Comment: @tkausl Electron allows a true fullscreen and only uses libchromiumcontent, NW.js uses more of Chromium than Electron does, so I don't see why it would be far-fectched to expect a true fullscreen option from NW.js.